# Error in sending SMS on button. android

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new to android development. and trying to send predefined sms on button click. Whenever click on button error showing java.lang.SecurityException: Sending SMS message: User 10134 does not have android.permission.SEND_SMS.I have taken  static 2 data types

```
BigInteger phoneNumber = new BigInteger("9876543210");
String smsBody="Ping";
```

My Main file is :-

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    if(v==ping) {
        try {

            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber.toString(), null, smsBody.toString(), null, null);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your sms has successfully sent!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your sms has failed...",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

my Manifest file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.devil.restro_final" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/icc"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Login_page" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Registration_page" />
        <activity android:name=".Booking_page" />
        <activity android:name=".admin_page" />
        <activity android:name=".User_page" />
        <activity android:name=".order" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Please suggest me where I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare the user permission tag first before the application tag. Refer this android documentation about [Structure of the manifest file](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html).

And Change your Manifest file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.devil.restro_final" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/icc"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />    
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Login_page" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Registration_page" />
        <activity android:name=".Booking_page" />
        <activity android:name=".admin_page" />
        <activity android:name=".User_page" />
        <activity android:name=".order" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

Move

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

out of

```
<application
```

like

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<application
...
```